# Quadratic terms in QED lagrangian density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

I recently learned that when we speak about a "free lagrangian", this actually means that the lagrangian is *quadratic in the fields*. When considering the Lagrangian density describing the coupling to electro-magnetic field:

${\mathcal{L}=\bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m)\Psi}-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$,
(where $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ieA_{\mu}$)

one must then encounter some terms that are not *quadratic in the field*.

My question is what are the terms that are not *quadratic* in the QED lagrangian and why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the $\bar \Psi \gamma^\mu A_\mu \Psi$ term, which is not quadratic in the fields, as there occur three fields multiplied together.

Comment: $D_\mu$ depends on a field and modifies the kinetic term by a cubic interaction.